# How to open an activity, input data, and get back to the first activity with the data?

Tags: android, android-intent

OK, the title isnt that much of a title but dont judge me.I've searched the website, and a lot other but i just dont seem to find the right answer. the problem is this:

I've created an android app that has one main activity(Activity A), it opens another activity B, where i put in some data, that data should be transferred back into the first activity, and then recorded into the db.

i do it like this:

in actctivity A:

-I call a new intent, and then `startActivityForResult()` method.

in the second activity when i hit the save button this gets executed:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("date", dateText.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("time", timeText.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("text", taskText.getText().toString());
                setResult(100);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

when i get back to the first activity (the main one) this method gets called.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode==100)
{
            i = getIntent();
        String text = i.getStringExtra("text");
            String date = i.getStringExtra("date");
            String time = i.getStringExtra("time");
            Toast.makeText(this, text + "-" + date + "-" + time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

with the toast message i only get null values which means the data wasn't transferred from the second activity back to the first. can someone help me please, and btw the data should be saved into a database, but that is another problem, i just mentioned it in case it may help on not complicating things for me later on.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In button save click listener you need not to call `Intent` with startActivity(). It is simply like this

```
  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
      returnIntent.putExtra("SelectedBook",book);
      setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
      finish();
```

And in onActivityResult() get data with `Intent data`

See this [Example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html)

Comment: thnx abhi it worked. with the link you provided i got just the right answer :D

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to get data from a different activity,

1. The one you are using,the mistake being don't call `startActivity` and
   just call `finish();` [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)
2. Use static variables and directly enter data on those public string
   variables and get it  anywhere.
3. Use SharedPreferences and use the saved data anywhere by just using
   the key values,i.e not just in `onActivityResult` [link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity, you don't call startActivity. You either call [setResult(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) or [setResult(int, Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) and then `finish()`

In your first activity, you retrieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

try using this in the second activity

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("SelectedBook",book);
returnIntent.putExtra("date", dateText.getText().toString());
returnIntent.putExtra("time", timeText.getText().toString());
returnIntent.putExtra("text", taskText.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
finish();
```

and in the first activity try using

```
data.getStringExtra("date");
```

and similarly the remaining.

Comment: you are welcome.. and sorry to say Its Sharath and not Sarath